# Are there useful categorical characterisations of the topological separation axioms?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Tietze's extension theorem states: If $X$ is a normal space, and $A$ a closed subspace. Then any continuous function to the reals $f:A\rightarrow R$ has an extension to $f':X\rightarrow R$ that is $f=f'i$ where $i$ is the inclusion of $A$ in $X$.

This can instead be used to characterize normal spaces. With this definition there is an easy proof of Urysohn's Lemma.

Essentially this is a categorical characterization of Normality. Are there similarly nice & useful categorical characterizations of the other separation axioms?

There is also one for Tichonov spaces - these are completely regular $T_1$ spaces (in fact it always turns out that they are $T_2$). They always have Hausdorff compactifications (a Hausdorff compact space within which they embed densely) and this characterises them. Since there is always a maximal compactification - the Stone-Čech compactification. This gives a categorical charactisation of Tichonov spaces.

Comment: You really ought to specify: Tikhonov spaces always have **Hausdorff** compactifications. (For some of us a compactification is simply an embedding as a dense subset of a compact space, and compact spaces are not necessarily Hausdorff.)

Comment: @Scott: ok, done. It ought to have been Tikhonov spaces rather than completely regular spaces.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What a funny coincidence, I've just attended a talk by M. Gavrilovich about categorical characterizations of basic notions of general topology.

Recall the notion of [orthogonality](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/orthogonality) in a category, and that partial orders can be viewed as topological spaces ([Alexandrov topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology)).

- A space $X$ is connected iff $X \to \{\bullet\}$ is left orthogonal to $\{\bullet,\bullet\} \to \{\bullet\}$
- A map $f : X \to Y$ is injective iff it is right orthogonal to $\{\bullet,\bullet\} \to \{\bullet\}$
- A map $f : X \to Y$ is surjective iff it is right orthogonal to $\emptyset \to \{\bullet\}$
- A space $X$ is Hausdorff iff every injective map $\{\bullet,\bullet\} \to X$ is left orthogonal to $\{a < b > a'\} \to \{\bullet\}$
- A space $X$ is compact iff $\emptyset \to X$ is left orthogonal to $\coprod_{\beta<\alpha} \beta \to \alpha$ for every limit ordinal $\alpha$.
- As you say, $X$ is normal iff every closed embedding $A \hookrightarrow X$ is left orthogonal to $\mathbb{R} \to \{\bullet\}$

Comment: Very interesting! But do you mean "lifting property" instead of "orthogonal" in some of these?

Comment: Its interesting that they're all expressed in terms of the same concept - orthogonality. Nlab has an alternative characterisation for $X$ a [connected space](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/connected+space) - when its representable functor $hom[X,-]$ preserves coproducts.

Comment: Presumably you mean that you _attended_ a talk?

Comment: Where can I find proofs of these characterizations?

Comment: I don't know, but the proofs are trivial and just use the definitions. Perhaps you may want to have a look at http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.6710.pdf, the paper by M. Gavrilovich about this.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Yes, and note also that the nLab definition of "connected space" disallows the empty space, whereas the definition here allows it. One can find a lot of commentary on such conventions, for example here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120536/is-the-empty-graph-a-tree/120580